# Chek if username and password are correct in mongodb with python code

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I tried to check credentials but it doesn't work, to the python code with mongodb

I'm new to the world of python and `mongodb`, I'm writing a client application that connects to a `mongodb` database;
I am stuck in the control if the username and password are correct 
I have also tried to capture the exceptions resulting from denied permission, but the code does not take it.
can someone help me?
the DB name is `alphadb`

```
get username e password from txtbox
    username=txtuser.get()
    password=txtpsw.get()

    client=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
    client=MongoClient('mongodb://'+username+':'+password+'@127.0.0.1:27017/alphadb')
```

I expect  a control to print in console access denied or success access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the code that you already tried!

Try this,

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.alphadb // assume your db name 'alphab'
user_collection = db.users // assume your collection name 'users'
user = user_collection.find_one({"username": "INPUT_USERNAME", "password": "INPUT_PASSWORD"})
if user:
    print("success access")
else:
    print("access denied")
```

You can see the tutorial from [official docs of pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

Warning: Anyway, you shouldn't save the raw password in the database. You can save the **hashed password** and the **salt** key. In your server's authentication logic, you have to implement a private logic that can decode/encode to validate the credentials.

Most of the popular framework or [MEAN stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)) already did it for you.

Comment: I had created a user and password and then given the roles on a specific db (alphadb) and I wanted to check the user and password at the beginning without going to create a users collection in alphadb, the given solution is fine, when I create a specific user I do 2 scripts, one as a collection in the db and the other I assign the role in db from console mode;

Comment: I don't see how this solution would work: MongoDB doesn't store passwords *in-the-clear* so you can't just do a `find()` on `system.users` - this would be a security hole if you could do this. If you're suggesting a custom collection for storing app-level usernames and passwords, this would also be a security issue. MongoDB never stores passwords in-the-clear, and app-level credentials should never be stored in-the-clear.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Save raw password is not a good practice. But if you want to store raw password, MongoDB does not prevent you!

Comment: So... to be clear: You're giving advice to a *brand new* MongoDB user, to store passwords in-the-clear (a known Bad Idea and anti-pattern). Of course MongoDB won't prevent you from doing something of a high-risk nature like this. But nobody should be doing this. Ever.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I just want to answer the direct problem of the question that **the code does not work**